# What WWII fighter raid did my great-uncle misremember?

Tags: world-war-two

My great-uncle Kevin Riordan was an Australian WWII fighter pilot. Some time around the year 2000, not long before he died, he wrote up his war memoirs. According to his memoirs:

- Joined the RAAF on November 4, 1941, initially training in Australia before shipping out to the UK via San Francisco and Boston, somewhere around late 1942/1943.
- Introduced to Spitfires in UK, completing "revision of service training" on 26 May 1943 and posted to 53 Operational Training Unit at Kirton-Lindsey. "By now I had a total of over 250 flying hours and was expected to be competent to normal flying. Now it was time to learn to use the aircraft as a fighting platform. This meant learning operational formation, air to air gunnery, fighter tactics, ..."
- Mentions heading into Lincoln to a pub while on leave and meeting an American officer who turned out to be Clark Gable, celebrating his 42nd birthday. If correct, this would've been February 1, 1943, which puts it *before* the completion of his service training revision.
- Posted to "Balado Bridge, an air gunnery school" on 9 October 1943.
- By around March 1944 after training he was flying Spitfires out of the UK with 130 (Punjab) Spitfire Squadron, temporarily renamed to 186 Squadron.
- Flew missions in support of D-Day, got shot down on D+7 while patrolling but got back safely (some unkind comments about American friendly fire here).
- On 29 June 1944, withdrawn from operations, returned to Lympne and converted to Spitfire XIVs.
- Describes trying to intercept "German flying bombs" (V1s presumably).
- On 20 September 1944 he was briefed on a support operation for hundreds of aircraft towing gliders headed for Arnhem.
- Some time after that 130 Squadron was moved to Grave to protect bridges from air attack.
- In November they moved to Diest, still in Holland.

Here's the bit I'm curious about:

> This morning the briefing was most unusual. It appears the Germans
> were using the Philips factory in Eindhoven to manufacture
> sophisticated electrical parts for their new aircraft. It had been
> decided not to bomb the factory, but to destroy the one floor which
> was being used. The factory was 4 stories, the Germans were using the
> 3rd floor. We were to destroy the 3rd floor by machine gun and cannon
> fire through the windows. The management was to use some pretext to
> evacuate the building so there would be no loss of life. It was a tall
> order - we would have to open fire at maximum range to give ourselves
> time to clear the building. There was no way we could practice, so it
> was a matter of "go in cold".
>
> At the appointed time we arrived over the target, assumed line-astern
> formation about 200 yards apart and took turns attacking the third
> floor. We continued this until we had used all our ammunition, then
> returned to base. The information was that the operation had been most
> successful. This was later confirmed when a representative of Philips
> arrived at the drome and presented each of the pilots who took part in
> the operation with an electric shaver, quite uncommon at that time.

The follow paragraph mentions a move "to Asch in Belgium", still in November, so this raid apparently took place some time in November 1944 between moves to Diest and moves to Asch.

It's an interesting story that has been part of family lore for years, but on checking the details I don't think it can have happened as described. Eindhoven was liberated on 18 September 1944 so I doubt my great-uncle would have been shooting it up two months later, nor would Philips have been giving out presents if he had...

Wiki records two raids on this factory: a major RAF bombing raid ([Operation Oyster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Oyster)) in 1942, and a follow-up raid by ten Mosquitos on 30 March 1943.

His description doesn't match Operation Oyster at all - a precisely targeted fighter raid, vs. a bomber raid. As far as I can tell he was still in training at the time of the March 1943 raid and there's no mention in his memoirs of flying Mosquitos - he goes into some detail on the specs of the planes he's flown so it would be a surprise if he didn't mention this.

So I'm curious as to what event he might have been describing. My best guess is that the raid he flew was targeted somewhere else, and that when he wrote up his memoirs many years later his memory blurred the details with a more famous operation. The detail of the shavers is curious, but I guess it's possible that he heard that story from the pilots of a previous raid and misremembered it as something that had happened to him.

Any ideas? I don't know if it will be possible to answer this definitively, unless somebody has detailed records for 130 Squadron available, but I'd be interested to hear of any plausible candidates.

Comment: I *seriously* doubt that this kind of precision gunnery was *possible*, let alone attempted in a nap-of-the-earth strike over enemy territory. No offense intended to your great-uncle, but I have seen quite a lot of gun camera footage ([example](https://youtu.be/ALH2LazrzgE?t=165)), and there is no way that a bunch of random pilots could be asked to (and succeed at) surgically taking out a specific story of a buiding by MG fire. (ctd.)

Comment: And with telling the factory beforehand so they could evacuate, and then a representative appearing at the aerodrome to "present" the pilots with a gift? There was still an active frontline between your great-uncle and that target, and the RAF did not have a history of telling targets of an incoming raid beforehand (or, actually, caring about collateral damage that much). Again, no offense intended, but I am afraid your great-uncle spun a bit of yarn there.

Comment: I agree with DevSolar, the precision was not possible then and the dates are wrong. [Memoirs have to be treated carefully as sources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGm7XwX7t0c). It reminds me of [Operation Jericho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Jericho), not in detail, but in concept.

Comment: The following link contains an intelligence report gathered by a team who visited the Philips factory in Eindhoven shortly after it was liberated. It contains information about other Philips operations in Germany and elsewhere which were attacked around that time. There may be something you can use if you can find out what targets your uncle's squadron was attacking. Maybe the guys from Eindhoven were just the ones who gave the presents. https://www.dos4ever.com/EF50/CIOS.pdf

Comment: Other dubious parts: 1) Specialist operations took a long time to prepare (dambusters, bombing the Tirpitz). 2) Finding which was the 3rd floor of a building you are approaching to and aiming your guns to it would have been definitely difficult. 3) The destructive power of aircraft cannons was not very good, and they did not have much ammunition (not to mention they probably wanted some to protect themselves on their way home). 4) If deemed necessary, the Allies had no major issue bombing civilians in occupied countries. Collateral damage was usually considered acceptable.

Comment: Perhaps the raid was targeted at another Philips plant using intelligence and assistance from the staff at the Eindhoven plant after its liberation. If there was a concerted effort to limit collateral damage, and there was already an existing relationship between the Philips people at Eindhoven and the RAF then the gifts afterwards might have been a fairly understandable gesture. The actual precision of the attack may have been exaggerated somewhat, but may have been appreciated by the company.

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks, and no offense taken. I'm aware that military exploits have a way of growing in the telling, and sixty years between the action and the memoir is plenty of time for inaccuracies to creep in, so I'm not tremendously surprised to hear that there are some other issues with this story. My great-uncle had a good long life and is no longer in a position to take any offense whatsoever.

Comment: Maybe we should not discard that your great uncle is telling real events, but no necessary events where he was present. This makes sense with the event of Philips, but also the one related to Clark Gable. Those two events are so special that surely many pilots remember the anecdotes, and also explain the inconsistency of dates, because he was not present.

Comment: @Santiago AFAICT it's quite possible that he did meet Clark Gable, and just misremembered it as happening around May instead of February. My best guess with the Eindhoven story is that it's a conflation of real events he was present for and others that he heard about (quite possibly exaggerated in the telling).

Comment: I’m currently working on a project for a gentleman who flew Spitfires in 130 squadron with your great uncle. His name is Fred Riley and he is 101 years old. I have the squadron records and can help with your question. I have been attempting to contact Shepparton library regarding Kevin Riordan’s book but have had no luck.

Comment: @JosephMack Perhaps the "memoir" was a family history project that was only shared privately within the family.

Comment: @AgentOrange That is correct, although somehow it's acquired a [Google Books entry](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/A_Wing_and_a_Prayer.html?id=wqC2zQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y). I'm now in touch with Joseph offline and he has a copy.

Answer (score 4):

RAF Operations Record Books (ORBs) are available at The National Archives; 130 Squadron's ORB for November 1944 is: https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/D8387862 (a free download for registered users at the time of writing). Usually there would be both a Form 540 (general summary of events) and a Form 541 (detailed records of events), but it seems most of the Form 541s are missing.

There doesn't appear to be anything corresponding to a precision raid in that month, just a number of armed reconnaissance missions (searching and attacking targets of opportunity).

130 Squadron was part of the 2nd Tactical Air Force (TAF). Christopher Shores and Chris Thomas wrote a very comprehensive three-volume history of the 2nd TAF and there were at least two precision fighter-bomber raids in November 1944 against targets in the Netherlands: the Amsterdam Gestapo HQ on November 26th and the Rotterdam Gestapo HQ on November 29th. They don't quite match the description (the buildings were bombed in both cases rather than specific floors targeted), and they were flown by the Hawker Typhoons of 146 Wing rather than Spitfires. As per your comment it sounds like a conflation of the earlier Eindhoven raids with 146 Wing's pinpoint attacks.